# validation subnet address range under vnet address range through c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a scenario which is that I have created a virtual network on azure with a address range in CIDR block e.g. 10.0.0.0/24 then a default subnet needs to be created which have a address range in similar CIDR block e.g. 10.1.0.0/16. I need to validate that subnet address range should resides in virtual network address range means i need to validate that 10.1.0.0/16 is in range of 10.0.0.0/24 or not?

I search it over the internet but I get only IP address validation under CIDR block but what i want is to validate CIDR block is in range under other CIDR block like the validation done on azure portal while creating virtual networks and subnets. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far? In which part of your code is the error?

Comment: actually I didnt find any code which validate cidr range under cidr range. The code which I find It only validates the IP under CIDR range but  not CIDR range under CIDR range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what i want is to validate CIDR block is in range under other CIDR block like the validation done on azure portal while creating virtual networks and subnets

For CIDR range comparison, I assumed that you could leverage the `IPNetwork.Contains` method from [IPNetwork](https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork) as follows:

```
IPNetwork addressSpaceRange = IPNetwork.Parse("172.20.0.0/24");
IPNetwork subnetAddressRange = IPNetwork.Parse("172.20.0.0/25");

Console.WriteLine($"Address space [{addressSpaceRange.ToString()}]:");
Console.WriteLine($"FirstUsable address:{addressSpaceRange.FirstUsable}");
Console.WriteLine($"LastUsable address:{addressSpaceRange.LastUsable}\r\n");

Console.WriteLine($"Subnet address range [{subnetAddressRange.ToString()}]:");
Console.WriteLine($"FirstUsable address:{subnetAddressRange.FirstUsable}");
Console.WriteLine($"LastUsable address:{subnetAddressRange.LastUsable}\r\n");

Console.WriteLine("addressSpaceRange contains subnetAddressRange:" + IPNetwork.Contains(addressSpaceRange, subnetAddressRange));
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Moreover, per my testing, this method only check whether the subnet address range is contained by address space, I assumed that the validation checking for subnet address and address would be handled on Azure side.